# Do they make wireless safety sensors for garage door openers?

Tags: garage, garage-door-opener, garage-door

I've had a lot of issues with the safety sensors for my garage door opener, most of which had to do with loose or broken wires leading from the opener to the sensors. It's been extremely frustrating when out of the blue the garage door won't close because even though the sensors are aligned, the wire got bumped and now doesn't have strong enough of a connection. So I've been searching for wireless sensors but wasn't really seeing anything come up. Do wireless sensors even exist? Or would that violate whatever code exists about safety sensors?

Comment: use `split loom` to protect the wires

Answer (score 5):

I've never seen them. The battery maintenance would be a hassle anyway.

Route and secure your wires appropriately to protect them, and build wood or metal guards around the sensor area to prevent careless people from banging into them. A simple block alongside the unit should do unless your home is populated by maniacs.

Comment: Children under the age of 5 often count as maniacs.

Comment: I wonder if you could mount the sensors to boxes and route the wires through EMT? That'd at least keep the wiring safe!

Answer (score 1):

They do make them. Few companies do. Miller Edge, Igazeb35, Banner engineering. Most are made for commercial purposes. They are "monitored" so the system always knows if they are working or not. If they are dead or not working the door will not close.

Comment: Note that I suspect that most of these sensors would not meet UL requirements for *residential* use -- commercial and residential openers are handled much differently by UL 325.